# Using data in classes when button pressed objective C/iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

New to iOS and I can't figure out this simple thing. (Been googling for ages)

So I've got a class which I've initiated in the ViewController.m viewDidLoad,

```
Student *person = [[Student alloc] init];

person.firstName = @"test";
```

I've created a button, and on the button pressed method I've tried to NSLog whatever's in the firstname variable but I keep getting a null result. I add the initialisation into the method and it works fine.

is there anyway I can just call the data that's been added from the viewDidLoad?

Thanks

edit:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

    Student *person = [[Student alloc] init];

    person.firstName = @"test";

}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"%@", person.firstName);
}
@end
```

Comment: It seems that 'person' is a local variable in `viewDidLoad` is it?

Comment: Please provide all your code as it appears in xcode, but more then likely `person` is local to `viewDidLoad` so your button method doesn't know about `person` instance in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: ahhhh yeah I guess it would be, I've tried adding Static in front but I'm getting no luck. is there another way? thanks

Comment: @Javanoob33 make it an instance of your viewController

Comment: Why would you just add static???? How would that help? And why have you just re-added code that you have already shared?? We want the code that you haven't shared yet.

Comment: I'm only new to iOS popeye, I just googled public variables to gain an idea. okay thanks Andrey I'll try that. didn't copy paste correctly, adding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `person` locally to `viewDidLoad` so the `buttonPressed:` method will know nothing of it. Change to below and read comments for explanation.

`MyViewController.h`

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

// No need to create ivar as this is done for you automatically
// Declaring this property here will make it public if you don't want it public 
// so code above @implementation
@property (nonatomic, strong) Student *person; 

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

`MyViewController.m`

```
@interface MyViewController()
// Doing it here will make it private to this class only.
// @property (nonatomic, strong) Student *person; 
@end

@implementaiton MyViewController

// No need for @synthesize as this is now done automatically as well
// Because @synthesize is called automatically you can just use _person or self.person

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Initialization of the person instance
    _person = [[Student alloc] init];
    // Setting the firstName of the person instance
    _person.firstName = @"Test";
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // NSLog the firstName
    NSLog(@"Student's first name : %@", _person.firstName);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need ivar or property. For example add ivar to your .m file:

```
@implementation YOURCLASSNAME
{
    Student *person;
}

//... other code

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    person = [[Student alloc] init];

    person.firstName = @"test";
}
//... Later in the same file when the button event is called
-(IBAction)buttonTapped {
    NSLog(@"%@", person.firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about you make the `person` a property.

In your controller header file

```
@interface Controller: UIViewController 
@property (nonatomic, retain) Student *person;
@end
```

And in your controller implementation file

```
@implementation
@synthesize person;
@end
```

This way the person property should be visible to your button IBAction.

And of course you'll need to change the following in your viewDidLoad from

```
Student *person = [[Student alloc] init];
```

to

```
person = [[Student alloc] init];
```

Comment: `"What about you make the person variable an instance variable"` -  where's the ivar then? Why the need for `@synthesize person;`? -1

Comment: My bad. Corrected the description of the suggested solution to use a property.